# Copying all files in directory based on filename pattern match

Tags: linux, bash, scp

I am new to linux commands use pattern matching. In my local folder, I have many .txt files with certain endings.

```
foobar_type01.txt
foobar_type02.txt
foobar_type03.txt
baz_type01.txt
baz_type02.txt
baz_type03.txt
```

My goal is to `scp` all of the files from my directory to a server that end with `...type03.txt`  so in this case only the following would be copied:

```
foobar_type03.txt
baz_type03.txt
```

What is the correct command to scp filename matches as opposed to extensions?  All I have been able to do is use the extension pattern

```
scp -C -r  /my_folder/*.txt server@10.10.55.28:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scp -C -r  /my_folder/*type03.txt server@10.10.55.28:`

Comment: Pattern matching on the shell is universal. In situations like this you can even do a test first to see what's found: e.g. `ls /my_folder/*type03.txt`